# Validating form of XML in Java

Tags: java, xml

How do I just validate the well-formedness of an XML file in Java?

Comment: Validation isn't the same thing as well-formedness. To check a document for well-formedness you can just try to parse it. If it's not well-formed the parse will fail. Validation requires that the document be written to a schema (eg DTD) to check against.

Comment: @bobince, my bad. My intentionetion was to check for well-formedness. So I would simply parse the xml string and check for errors?

Comment: Mostly yes. A non-well-formed document won't parse at all. Except there is one wrinkle: if you have a `<!DOCTYPE>` with an external subset that defines entities, you will need to tell the parser to fetch ‘external entities’ (the external subset and any external `<!ENTITY>`​s referenced) to be sure that every `&entity;` reference in the document has been defined somewhere. A non-external-entity-including parser can't be 100% sure a document is well-formed if it contains entity references that are externally defined.

Comment: This is pretty messy... really everything to do with DTD in XML is a disaster, but there we go. Luckily DTD is used less and less these days as everyone hates it. Hopefully you can get away without externally-defined entities.

Answer (score 1):

You could try "The Java XML Validation API"

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use a validating parser:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;

SAXParserFactory factory=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(true);
SAXParser parser=pf.newSAXParser();
```

DocumentBuilderFactory has a similar method.

From the JavaDoc:

> setValidating
>
> public void setValidating(boolean validating)
>
> Specifies that the parser produced by this code will validate documents
>   as they are parsed. By default the
>   value of this is set to false.
>
> Note that "the validation" here means a validating parser as defined
>   in the XML recommendation. In other
>   words, it essentially just controls
>   the DTD validation. (except the legacy
>   two properties defined in JAXP 1.2.)
>
> To use modern schema languages such as W3C XML Schema or RELAX NG
>   instead of DTD, you can configure your
>   parser to be a non-validating parser
>   by leaving the setValidating(boolean)
>   method false, then use the
>   setSchema(Schema) method to associate
>   a schema to a parser.
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
>     validating - true if the parser produced by this code will validate documents as they are parsed; false otherwise.false otherwise.
> ```